# Couldn't get maven version

Tags: maven, apt-get

I'm using Ubuntu and new to maven i started to install maven 3 with

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/
3.1.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.1.0-bin.tar.gz
```

i need to install this version to be convenient with JDK6 after that i extracted this in /opt

then edited in .bashrc

```
export MVN_HOME="/tmp/apache-maven-3.1.0"
export PATH="$PATH:$MVN_HOME/bin"
```

i tested `mvn -version` but got

`The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`

Comment: Why do you reference a `src` folder ? The tar.gz does not contain that directory. Use bin directly

Comment: yes i unpack it , i used src folder as it has bin but i deleted it and problem still i mean i wrote it MVN_HOME="/opt/apache-maven-3.1.0

Comment: So _please_ update your question because it is just misleading. What happens when you call `/opt/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin/mvn`? Besides that you should try to put $MVN _before_ $PATH because you want to change what comes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked which directories are already in `$PATH` and contain a `mvn` ?

Change your export statement to

```
export PATH="$MVN_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

in order to make sure that your mvn comes first. Besides that you might want to scan for variants of mvn that are already on your system:

```
find / -name mvn
```